What is the command to clear an entire line in Linux using Super + Backspace, like on Mac with Command (hold) + Backspace (tap)?
I’m looking to create a custom shortcut on Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 24.04) to clear an entire line using Super + Backspace, similar to how it works on Mac with Command (hold) + Backspace (tap).
My goal is to clear the entire line with just a few keys in any app that support text input, making the process quick and efficient.

Where in Linux? In the terminal? In a text editor?

@mook765 Normally in browser or any apps where text input can be done.

Relevant information should be in your question but not in a coment, please edit for clarification. I think that's application specific and can't be done with a global shortcut. The answer below works for terminal only, even with nano editor (inside a terminal) it will not.

@mook765, that's true. I have updated my answer so that the shortcut can be used in most of the apps.

it's nifty how all text fields on macOS are uniform like this

I've updated the question. Thank you.

For Terminals:
Some shortcuts already exist in the terminal to clear an entire line. They are as follows:

Ctrl + U: Clears from the cursor position to the beginning of the line.

Ctrl + K: Clears from the cursor position to the end of the line.

Ctrl + A + K: This will move the cursor to the beginning of the line (Ctrl + A) and
clears the entire line (Ctrl + K).


If you specifically want your Super + Backspace to clear the whole line, then you should create a custom shortcut that will trigger the above keys with the help of xdotool.

Install xdotool using apt:
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install xdotool


Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.

Click on the add button, give it a name, set the shortcut, and add the following command:
xdotool key ctrl+a+k




You can customize the command with other shortcuts based on your requirements.

For Browsers and similar apps
If you are looking to clear a line in browsers or similar apps, you can try the following shortcuts:

Shift + Delete:  This will delete the entire line in most of the Text editors and IDEs.

If you are looking to delete lines only in browsers or similar apps, then you can edit the Custom Shortcut command as follows:
xdotool key Home keydown Shift key End key Delete keyup Shift

This command will bring the cursor to the beginning of the line, select the line to its end, and then delete it. This is a combination of Shift, Home, and End keys along with Delete. You can change the Delete key to Backspace key by editing the command. Also, note that this shortcut won't work for terminals.

Note: As mook765 mentioned in comments, several applications like most text editors (especially terminal editors) use different shortcuts to achieve line deletion. So it's better to learn the shortcuts on those editors.

Thank you for such a detailed answer. I needed for an app, the shortcut for text editors, but I needed it in other apps. Thank you again for your time.
